# Windows Store App - disabling system menu

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm developing version of may application targeted for Windows 8.1 desktop as Store app. I'm wondering if it's possible to disable default upper left menu icon?

[image: example]